# How to transpose rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following data in Oracle

```
Number   Text
12345    ab 
12345    abc   
12345    acbd
```

How can I convert it to become:

```
Number   Text1 Text2 Text3
12345    ab    abc   abcd
```

How to do this using SQL in Oracle?

Comment: What exactly you would like to do with your data? You want to insert or select from your table?

Comment: Look at the PIVOT operator from Oracle 11.

Answer (score 1):

In order to rotate the multiple rows of data into columns, first I would use `row_number()` and then you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the final result:

```
select "Number",
  max(case when seq = 1 then "Text" end) Text1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then "Text" end) Text2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then "Text" end) Text3
from
(
  select "Number", "Text",
    row_number() over(partition by "Number" order by "Text") seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by "Number";
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a94a/1)